# hql join @CollectionTable

Tags: hibernate, hql, jpql

**I have a domain `Service` with collection `tags` as below :**

```
@Entity
public class Service extends AbstractEntity<Long> {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 9116959642944725990L;

        @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, targetClass = java.lang.String.class)
        @CollectionTable(name = "service_tags", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "s_id"))
        @Column(name = "tag")
        private Set<String> tags;
    }
```

I want to select `Service`s `with` particular `KEY` of `Service.tags`.

**`hql` joining `Service` to `Service.tags` is as below :**

```
select s from Service s INNER JOIN s.tags t where s.status=0 and (s.serviceType=9 or t.tag in ('College'))
```

**But, above hql returns me with following exception :**

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: cannot dereference scalar collection element: tag [select s from com.zazzercode.domain.Service s INNER JOIN s.tags t where s.status=0 and (s.serviceType=9 or t.tag in ('College')) ]
```

`select s from Service s INNER JOIN s.tags t where s.status=0` works though.

Looking at [JPQL querying a collection of non-entites](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9311242/432903), I tried like below

```
"select s from Service s where s.status=0 and s.priviligedUser.priviligedUserType IN (2,4) and (s.serviceType=9 or (KEY(s.tags)='tag' and (VALUE(s.tags)='College'))"
```

**Got following exception :**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: null near line 1, column 188 [select s from com.esewa.server.entity.Service s where s.status=0 and (s.serviceType=9 or (KEY(s.tags)='tag' and (VALUE(s.tags)='College'))]
```

I have achieved same thing [using criteria api](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14795429/432903) some months back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to [JPQL querying a collection of non-entites](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9311242/432903)

#### Following code works !!!

```
"select s from Service s INNER JOIN s.tags t where s.status=0 and and (s.serviceType=9 or  VALUE(s.tags) in ('College')) "
```

Comment: This accepted answer does not work for me because VALUE is only meant for Maps, but this here is a Collection.

Answer (score 3):

```
"select s from Service s where s.status=0 and (s.serviceType=9 or 'College' in elements(s.tags))"
```